# How to pass data from UICollectionViewCell inside TableViewCell to another ViewController with UIColletcionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have three classes: `MainViewController`, `MagazineTableViewCell` and `MagazineCollectionViewCell`. Please, check screenshot from storyboard - 
[image]

Look at my `MainViewController`:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "magazineCell", for: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell

        self.magazine = cell.magazine

        return cell
    }
     else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newInWomenCell", for: indexPath) as! NewInWomenTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewInMenCell", for: indexPath) as! NewInMenTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

My `TableViewCell` class :

```
class MagazineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var magazine = [Magazine]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return magazine.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "magazineCell", for: indexPath) as! AllMagazineCollectionViewCell

        cell.set(magazine: magazine[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

And my last class `UICollectionViewCell` :

```
class AllMagazineCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    }

    func set(magazine: Magazine) {
        ImageService.getImage(withURL: magazine.imageOfMagazine) { image in
            self.image.image = image
        }
    }

}
```

How i can pass data from UICollectionViewCell to another view controller?

Func prepare for segue is now working in `MainViewController` and in MagazineTableViewCell this func is not call.

Sorry for my Eng.

Comment: Do you want to pass cell data when cell is touched to another VC?

Comment: Did you take a look to the observer pattern?

Answer (score 0):

1-

```
class MagazineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   weak var main: MainViewController!
```

2-

```
class AllMagazineCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

  weak var main: MainViewController!
```

3-

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "magazineCell", for: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell
cell.main = self
```

4-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "magazineCell", for: indexPath) as! AllMagazineCollectionViewCell
    cell.main = main
```

5- Now you have main init it with any data when the cell is clicked and you can use it to perform the segue

```
main.performSegue////
```

inside the collectionCell

Comment: where i can write "main.performSegue"? I the "AllMagazineCollectionViewCell"?

Comment: yes you can call it in **AllMagazineCollectionViewCell**

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: In other viewController array equal nil

Answer (score -1):

You should not pass data from `UICollectionViewCell` to another view controller directly, its not a good design. You must have Delegation or completion handler callback from your `MagazineTableViewCell` to the `MainViewController` then from `MainViewController` you can pass data to another controller.

Use like this below:

```
class MagazineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
      var cellSelectionHandler: ((yourData: type) -> Void)? // Callback handler
}
```

Then in the `MagazineTableViewCell` class implement the collection view `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` then call the `cellSelectionHandler` from there and pass your required data to the handler.

And set your `cellSelectionHandler` in `MainViewController` as given below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "magazineCell", for: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell

        self.magazine = cell.magazine

        // Handle your callback here
        cell.cellSelectionHandler = { (yourData) in
           // Handle your data here and pass to another ViewController.
        }

        return cell
    }
     else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newInWomenCell", for: indexPath) as! NewInWomenTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewInMenCell", for: indexPath) as! NewInMenTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

**Completion handler example:**
For example you need to pass `Int` value to the completion handler:

// handler declaration

```
var cellSelectionHandler: ((index: Int) -> Void)?
```

// handler definition

```
cell.cellSelectionHandler = { (index) in
// use the index here
}
```

// Handler calling from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
cellSelectionHandler?(index) // pass your index of type Int
```

Any doubt plz comment.

Comment: i dont understand, how to pass data from didSelectItemAtIndexPath to the handler. Help me, please....

Comment: I have edited my ans, given one example how to use the handler, in the [didSelectItemAtIndexPath] UICollectionView delegate method you call the handler.

Comment: In the didSelectItemAtIndexPath :

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cellSectionHandler?.(magazines)
    }

I have error - Expected member name following '.'

Comment: remove the dot(.) in between  cellSectionHandler?.(magazines) - wrong cellSectionHandler?(magazines) -right way

Comment: okay, i added cellSectionHandler?(magazines[indexPath.row]), because i had error. Now, it's okay. 

How i can pass data from this handle in MainViewController? 

cell.cellSectionHandler = { (magazines) in
                //in this i dont understand what i must do
            }

Comment: my array magazines = [Magazine] 
struct Magazine {
let nameOfMagazine: String
let imageOfMagazine: URL
}

Comment: MainViewController? cell.cellSectionHandler = { (magazines) in //in this i dont understand what i must do } – here you will get the callback on selecting the collection cell. Also you get the magazines data here, now you can use this to pass to some other Controller or whatever you want to do.

Comment: i want to pass data for indexPath.row . I want to click on collectionViewcell (this is magazine). After, i want to see the next view with clothes of clicked magazine.

Comment: you pass data in your handler what data you want, and call the handler form didSelectItemAtIndexPath that's it. then you get a callback in MainViewController inside the block  { (magazines) in //in this i dont understand what i must do } , Do you have any knowledge of swift programming or not ?

Comment: what i must write in compl handler in cellforrawatindexpath?

Comment: then you must read about blocks in swift then you will understand.

Comment: add like this: cell.cellSelectionHandler = { (magazine) in
// use magazine data here i.e push to new VC.
}

Comment: why you give a negative voting when you can't understand the concept. First go and read before giving negative vote without knowing.